# Printer_open() to print a html output

Tags: php, html

With `printer_open()` function in php, I am able to print the string that I saved in `$content` variable, and able to print from a file.

```
$printer = "\\\\Pserver.php.net\\printername"; 
$handler = printer_open($printer);
$content = "Test Content";  //string
printer_write($handler, $content); 
printer_close($handler);
```

But have a html output that I generated from the database, and is showing in the webpage, I need to print that directly to the printed in the same format once the page loads, I tried a lot but I dont know what I should do to make the printer to print directly the same HTML output once the page loads using the `printer_open()`.

What should I do? Please suggest a better method than this if any

---

UPDATED

I dont want to use windows.print() method of javascript, since it shows the print dialogue box instead of initiating the printing job directly to the printer

I want users to hit submit form and printer to print the receipt directly without asking them anything

Comment: Do you want to print from the server or the client? Normally the server doesn't have access to the rendered HTML and you can't use PHP t print from the client, since PHP runs on the server.

Comment: @Rahul-TS you could try javascript window.print() function. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_print.asp

Comment: @RoToRa I am using client printer

Comment: @xurca The main issue that push me to this php code is print dialogue box that appear while window.print() runs, I am trying to print a receipt for a point of sales system, I want the printer to print once the sales is complete

Comment: It's possible to use an ActiveX control in some versions of IE to do this, but it's generally not possible to completely bypass a confirmation dialog box.

Comment: You can't avoid the print dialog, unless you use a browser that doesn't display (which doesn't exists AFAIK). You'd need to modify the browser in some way. Maybe it's possible with a browser plugin.

Comment: `printer_open()` (in PHP) is server side, `window.print()` (in JS) client side. So if a regular user will visit your page and PHP's `printer_open()` is called, the file will be printed on your server and the client won't see it...

Comment: @Reeno That's exactly what we need. Document printed on server without user seeing the content.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use output buffer:

```
ob_start();
// generate your output from the DB here
// .....

// Send generated output to the printer
printer_write($handler, ob_get_contents());

// And show it to client on the frontend
ob_end_flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

create a hidden field with autofocus (HTML5-capable browser needed) and trigger the printout with the html onblur attribute (output, if user hits any other form element) or the onfocus attribute on a specific form element (button). Dont't submit the form, because this would cause the page to be reloaded ....

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you're trying to render HTML and then print it. Unfortunately, if you render it client-side, you will need to print it client-side - which will initiate the print dialog.

You *could* run PhantomJS on the server to render the HTML, save a snapshot and print that, but that sounds like massive overkill just to print an invoice.

Probably better idea would be to generate a PDF and print that.